# Digitally sign my email (in WLM) with my GnuPG key?

Tags: email, windows-live-mail, gnupg

If I understand PGP correctly, I can digitally sign my email with my private key, which will prove they are from me, right?

I created my public and private key on my server, but I can't work out how to set up digital signing with Windows Live Mail. Just to be clear, I'm talking about my own domain email account and not a hotmail account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'd use a plug-in for Windows Live Mail, but I highly doubt one exists.  If it doesn't, you need to get a [front-end for GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/frontends.en.html).  If the front-end you choose allows you to encrypt the current window (you really want to find one that does this), you can type your email and then use the "Encrypt current window" option to clear sign or encrypt the text.  If it doesn't allow you to encrypt the current window, you have to cut the text to the clipboard, sign and/or encrypt the contents of the clipboard, and paste it back into your email.